# XSLT include and document('') collision

Tags: xml, xslt, document

I have two XSLT file **A**.xslt and **B**.xslt, where **A**.xslt *includes* **B**.xslt.

**A**.xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:my="my_namespace">

    <my:data>This is A.xslt</my:data> 

    <xsl:include href="B.xslt"/>

    <xsl:template name="my_template">
        <xsl:value-of select="$remote-data"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**B**.xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:my="my_namespace">

    <xsl:variable name="remote-data"
                   select="document('')/*/my:data" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course when **my_template** is evaluated, empty line is outputted. This happens because **B**.xslt does not cantain **my:data** container and `document('')` call is processed *before include*.

My question is: how can I access **my:data** from **B**.xslt (Make `document('')` to be processed *after inclusion*)?

Any ideas are appreciated!

**Update:** In real life I have multiple files like **A**.xslt: **A1**.xslt, **A2**.xslt,... and it is needed to make exactly the same calculations with nodeset as a result (like in `$remote-data` definition) but with different parameters (stored in **my:data**).

One can say that I can use named template for that. But as far as I can see it is not possible to do this, because template would return RTF, which I have to `node-set()` which is generally not available in XSLT 1.0 parsers.

Hope this clarifies my problem.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `document()` function invoked with an empty path will reference the source XML document of the XSLT that the code block "lives" in.  In this case, it is **B.xslt**.

If you want to load/reference XML from **A.xslt**, then change your line to:

```
<xsl:variable name="remote-data"
                   select="document('A.xslt')/*/my:data" />
```

Comment: +1 Good answer. The logic behind this `fn:document()` behavior is that an empty string argument is resolved as the **stylesheet URI** an the URI for `A.xslt` should be different from `B.xslt`.

Comment: @Savva: The update has nothing to do with the solution I am proposing -- it is sufficient to have the data defined in a single, global `<xsl:variable>` . Then this variable is accessible in all included/imported stylesheets. No need for any extension functions.

Answer (score 0):

**There are two possibilities**:

.1. As already recommended by @Mads-Hansen, use:

```
<xsl:variable name="remote-data" 
                   select="document('A.xslt')/*/my:data" />
```

.2. Move the definition of the $`remote-data` variable in A.xslt:

```
<xsl:variable name="remote-data"    
               select="document('')/*/my:data" />
```

Then it can be accessed by the code of B.xslt, because globally defined `<xsl:variable>` s are accessible in all included or imported stylesheet modules.